# BSOD in Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, 2 x 2GB DDR3 RAM, Intel Core i5 2.8Ghz, M.B. Intel DH55HC series machine which gives me the following BSOD.  The BSOD comes up randomly for no apparent observable event identifiable to me.

> Error : A problem has been detected
>   and Windows has been shut down to
>   prevent damage to your computer.
>
> The problem seems to be caused by the
>   following file: ntoskrnl.exe
>
> PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
>
> If this is the first time you've seen
>   this stop error screen, restart your
>   computer. If this screen appears
>   again, follow these steps:
>
> Check to make sure any new hardware or
>   software is properly installed. If
>   this is a new installation, ask your
>   hardware or software manufacturer for
>   any Windows updates you might need.
>
> If problems continue, disable or
>   remove any newly installed hardware or
>   software. Disable BIOS memory options
>   such as caching or shadowing. If you
>   need to use safe mode to remove or
>   disable components, restart your
>   computer, press F8 to select Advanced
>   Startup Options, and then select Safe
>   Mode.
>
> Technical Information:
>
> *** STOP: 0x00000050 (0xfffffa900395d270,
>   0x0000000000000000,
>   0xfffff80002df3070, 
>   0x0000000000000005)
>
> *** ntoskrnl.exe - Address 0xfffff80002cbf740 base at
>   0xfffff80002c4f000 DateStamp 
>   0x4cc791bd

Already tried: disabled BIOS caching shadowing etc, removing one of the RAM modules, installing Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (different than what is on the machine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running [Memtest86+](http://memtest.org/) to test for bad memory.

If you are still having problems, try running in safe mode and running prime95 or a similar stress testing tool. If the bluescreen doesn't show up, it is most likely a bad driver, however, if it does show up, you could have a bad motherboard (or unlikely, but a bad processor).

Comment: Spot on as always, Wil.  85% of the time I see this stop error it's a driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've seen this already: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Resolving-stop-blue-screen-errors-in-Windows-7

Since you installed Windows 7 Professional, was it a clean install? If it's still occuring following that, it might be a hardware issue.