# Windows 7 cannot update registry

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tracking down random BSOD on windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/130786/tracking-down-random-bsod-on-windows-7)
>   [BSOD in Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit](https://superuser.com/questions/276018/bsod-in-windows-7-ultimate-64-bit)

I have Windows 7 installed in my PC.

On first time start up, my system couldn't update the registry. The system automatically reboots and displays a blue screen with `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA` after booting.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: could you do a memory test with memtestx86 and see if you can copy out and upload the minidump file if any from c:/minidump ? This would be very helpful in diagnosing the exact issue and checking if its a memory issue. Further information on your hardware would be useful as well, is it a new system? What kind of and brand of ram? What processor, etc. Give as much information as you can.

Comment: or this one....http://superuser.com/questions/130786/tracking-down-random-bsod-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

A blue screen of death can be due to quite a few things. Firstly it could be driver issues - if your system has any minidump files, copying them out (say from another computer or linux livecd), would let you load them into [bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) - if you don't have another system, edit it into your question, comment here and I'll take a look.

It could also be due to bad memory, or other hardware issues - you can check your memory with [memtestx86+](http://www.memtest.org/)

Comment: I think you mean `question` not `answer`. If I'm getting you wrong Sir you can revert back.

Comment: Also as far as I searched for this Microsoft is asking for scan the system for viruses and malware.